# Updating and refreshing the values of AChartEngine in android

Tags: android, achartengine

I need to refresh the value of an AChartEngine. I am refreshing the GraphicalView and repainting the instance but the values are not getting updated.

I am two XYSeries as follows.

```
waterSeries = new XYSeries("values");
waterSeries.add(1, y1[0]);
waterSeries.add(2, y1[1]);
waterSeries.add(3, y1[2]);
waterSeries.add(4, y1[3]);
waterSeries.add(5, y1[4]);
waterSeries.add(6, y1[5]);
waterSeries.add(7, y1[6]);
waterSeries.add(8, y1[7]);
waterSeries.add(9, y1[8]);
waterSeries.add(10, y1[9]);
waterSeries.add(11, y1[10]);
waterSeries.add(12, y1[11]);

waterSeries2 = new XYSeries("values");
waterSeries2.add(1, y2[0]);
waterSeries2.add(2, y2[1]);
waterSeries2.add(3, y2[2]);
waterSeries2.add(4, y2[3]);
waterSeries2.add(5, y2[4]);
waterSeries2.add(6, y2[5]);
waterSeries2.add(7, y2[6]);
waterSeries2.add(8, y2[7]);
waterSeries2.add(9, y2[8]);
waterSeries2.add(10, y2[9]);
waterSeries2.add(11, y2[10]);
waterSeries2.add(12, y2[11]);
```

When I scroll a SeekBar these values are getting swapped. and I am trying to repaint the instance of GraphicalView class (grfv) as follows.

```
dataset = buildDataset(titles, x, values);
dataset.addSeries(0, series1);
dataset.addSeries(0, series2);
renderer.addSeriesRenderer(0, waterRenderer);
renderer.addSeriesRenderer(0, xxRenderer);
waterRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
waterRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(10);

String[] types = new String[] { BarChart.TYPE, LineChart.TYPE, LineChart.TYPE };
final GraphicalView grfv = ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(this, dataset, renderer,    types);
grfv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
grfv.repaint();
grfv.invalidate();
```

Please help me with any code to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.
Sundeep.S.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding the series and the renderers, you are using the version of the methods having the first parameter an index. Just use the `addSeries(series)` instead of `addSeries(index, series)` and the series will be displayed in the order you add them.

The same for the renderers.